# How to launch error pop up using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I want to display an `error message` when try is failing. What is best practice for doing this with MVVM? I am using `UWP` and `XAML`.

This Code is from my **ItemsViewModel**:

```
internal async Task LoadItemsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var items = await itemsDataAccess.GetAll("items");
        foreach (Item i in items)
            Items.Add(i);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Display error to user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one good answer here. One approach that I've used in the past is to have a central `DialogService` or `PopupService` that manages the creation and display of dialogs. This is doubly necessary, because attempting to open two `ContentDialog`s on the same thread simultaneously throws an exception (and `ContentDialog` is the recommended way to display modal content).

You could pass this Service class to your ViewModel by whichever means you have your viewmodels resolving dependencies, and then just use that service to display your popup.

My suggestion in a nutshell:

- Create your own `ErrorContentDialog` that inherits from`ContentDialog` (or just use a basic `ContentDialog` if that's sufficient for you)
- Create a `DialogService` that manages the creation of `ContentDialogs` (the one-dialog-per-thread limit mentioned up above, for example)
- Write a `ShowErrorDialog()` method for the `DialogService`. Depending on how you want to model your data, you could have it take a few simple parameters, or perhaps you could create an entire `ErrorContentDialogViewModel` which the caller is responsible for creating and passing in.
- Give your `ItemsViewModel` access to this `DialogService` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't get too hung up on trying to keep the error message in the MVVM pattern.

If it's just notification then use Toast to pop it up.

If you want actual user interaction then I'd navigate to a modal page.